# How to use standard controls like delete button or disclosure indicator in custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-controls, assets

I would like to create a custom `UITableViewCell` which works like the phone number cell in the Contacts App:

[image]

Is there some **build in** method to the **default controls** like the add / delete / disclosure buttons to my cell? Or do I have to create these assets myself?

Of course creating and using my own assets (e.g. using a simple button with an image) is not a big deal. However, using some build in controls / assets would have the big advantage that future design updates would become visible in my app automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are built in controls. Here you have [Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html) where you have described how to create delete functionality.

Also in Apple documentation about UITableCellView you can find [Editing Style](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/editingstyle) property which is adding controls to cells.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The Editing-Style and the Delete features are standard features of course. However, this is not what I asked. The question is, how I can add the standard controls / assets like the delete, add or detail cevron icon anywhere in a custom cell.

Comment: Ok. So yes you have access to the System icons. To use them you need to        open your view file, click "+" button (like you want to add some controls) and above the search bar you have 3 icons. When you click on "image" icon then you have a list of resources. At the beginning of the list you will have resources added into your project but when you scroll down then you will see the system ones.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can implement the method below:
At first, the ViewController has a property named "isEditing", which decides whether the cell is in the editable status.

```
extension UIViewController {

    open var isEditing: Bool

    open func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool)

    open var editButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem { get }
}
```

Then you must implement UITableView delegate methods like:

```
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
```

At last, when the variable "isEditing" is true, you can get what you want above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I appreciate the work you put into this. However, this has nothing to do with my question...